# Extend with dependent type

Tags: scala, extends, dependent-type, dotty, scala-3

Here is the minimal reproduction of my problem:

```
  trait Superclass[T]
  
  class A(val key: Any) extends Superclass[key.type]
  
  val x: Superclass["123"] = A("123")
```

As you can see, I'm trying to encode the statically known type of Key into the type parameter.
It's not like I can put the type of `key` as a type parameter of A, since in my real example, it's more like `class A(using g: blablah)(val key: g.Key) extends SuperClass[g.Mapping[key.type]]` but that's not relevant for the problem above.

Is it just that we can't use dependent types inside the arguments of the super class?

**Update**

The encoding with type members yields the same error:

```
  trait Superclass {
    type T
  }
  
  class A(val key: Any) extends Superclass {
    type T = key.type
  }
  
  val x: Superclass & {type T = "123"} = A("123")
```

I still get

```
[error] 14 |  val x: Superclass & {type T = "123"} = A("123")
[error]    |                                         ^^^^^^^^
[error]    |                Found:    Main.A
[error]    |                Required: Main.Superclass & Object{T = ("123" : String)}
```

Comment: Can you modify `Superclass` to have `T` as a type member instead of a parameter?

Comment: Just did. See the updated question.

Comment: And by the way, can you expose type parameters as type members with the same name?

Comment: If you're fine with juggling a dozen type parameters, here's a possible [solution](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hTVMXwvrTUKFkV38mz0k6A). It's not for the faint of heart, though.

Answer (score 1):

I could not work around your given example, but this may work for your actual use case.

```scala
trait Superclass[T]

//The type of G
trait Foo:
  type Key
  type Mapping[K <: Key]

class A [K, KT <: K, M[_ <: K], G <: Foo {type Key = K; type Mapping[T <: K] = M[T]}] private(val key: KT, g: G)
    extends Superclass[M[KT]]

object A:
  def apply[G <: Foo](using g: G)(key: g.Key) =
     new A[g.Key, key.type, g.Mapping, g.type](key, g)
```

And you can use it like this:

```scala
class FooImpl extends Foo:
  type Key = String
  type Mapping[S <: String] = List[S]

given myG as FooImpl = FooImpl()

val x: Superclass[List["123"]] = A[FooImpl]("123")
```

In `Foo`, `Key` is used to bound what keys can be given to `Mapping`. The `K` parameter on class `A` is `key`'s type's upper bound, while `KT` is the actual type of the key. `M` represents `Mapping`. I used a type refinement because type projections are unsound and have been dropped in Scala 3.

For convenience, you can add an `apply` method to `A`'s companion and make `A`'s own constructor private.

See it run in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hebzKZJISaSvCNlZZoyczw).

As for dependent types in constructors, see [this issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/5712). It looks like you can't use them the same way you can in methods.